# Self hosting Web API with OWIN on EC2

Tags: owin, asp.net-web-api2, self-hosting

I followed step-by-step instructions from http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api.

Here is the code of console application:

```
namespace OWINTest
{
class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://localhost:1961/";
        // Start OWIN host 
        WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress);
        ...
    }
  }
class Startup
  {
    // This code configures Web API. The Startup class is specified as a type
    // parameter in the WebApp.Start method.
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        // Configure Web API for self-host. 
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
  }
public class ValuesController : ApiController
  {
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
  }
}
```

The following is true:

1. OWIN server is running (can connect from the same machine using Fiddler, browser)
2. Port of EC2 instance is opened to inbound traffic via security group
3. No other processes are listening to that port
4. OWIN version is Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost 5.2.2
5. .NET 4.5 is installed on EC2 instance

Issue I run into:

```
HTTP/1.1 502 - Connection Failed error when calling http://(uc2-00-000-000-us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com):1961/api/values with the following message: The connection to 'ec2-00-000-000-us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' failed. Error: TimedOut (0x274c). System.Net.Sockets.SocketException A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

I tried the following without success:

```
 1. 'netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost:1961 user=everyone'
 2. 'netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:1961 user=everyone'
 3. 'netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:1961 user=everyone'
```

Comment: Besides opening up port 1961, you have to open up [Ephemeral Ports](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html#VPC_ACLs_Ephemeral_Ports).  That basically allows the server to open up a port to return the data back to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Use base address `http://+:1961/` and depending on which windows account you are running your owin server as you won't need the `urlacl`. 
ie:

- you're running your owin server as a windows service using the `local system` account then you won't need the urlacl.
- you're running the owin server from the command prompt while logged in the administrator account.