# Unable to Access Owin Self hosted RestApi - Deployed to AWS EC2 - Windows 2012 R2

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api, owin, windows-server-2012-r2, self-hosting

Following is the sample self hosting Rest API code, I have created with OWIN.
It is working in my local machine.

i have hosted it in aws-ec2, and started as administrator.

I am able to access the Rest API from inside the instance (using chrome/IE) giving localhost as URL.

[image: Access inside Instan]

But getting a Bad request invalid hostname, when i replace the localhost with public DNS of Instance (running within Instance's browser).

[image: Instance DNS name]

when i tried to access the RestApi from outside the instance browser from my local machine (browser/postman), it is returning status 0.

[image: Accessing from outside]

Copied the code below.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        const string BaseUri = "http://localhost:65435";
        Console.WriteLine("Starting web Server...");
        WebApp.Start<Startup>(BaseUri);
        ...
    }
}

public class Startup {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
        var webApiConfiguration = ConfigureWebApi();
        app.UseWebApi(webApiConfiguration);
    }

    private HttpConfiguration ConfigureWebApi() {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "DefaultApi",
            "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
        return config;
    }
}

public class CompaniesController : ApiController {
    public IEnumerable<Company> Get() {
        return new List<Company>(){
                       new Company() { Id = 1, Name = "Microsoft" },
                       new Company() { Id = 2, Name = "Amazon" }
                   };
    }
}
```

I have created a Windows Server 2012 R2 - AWS EC2 instance.

Configured the instance:

1. To allow all traffic in inbound and outbound.
2. Opened all ports.
3. I have disabled Windows Firewall
4. I have tried to ping the DNS name from my local machine cmd, and it was success.
5. Web API is using, port number - 65435 (Ephemeral Port)
6. Owin version - 5.2.3.0, .Net version - 4.5 (4.5.2 is installed on EC2 instance)
7. Changed the "localhost" in the code to public-dns (Same issue persists) and ip-address (throws an Exception - "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.")

[image: Inbound Rule]

[image: Outbound Rule]

Please help me to configure this.

Comment: to me it looks like your webserver isn't listening for that hostname, and instead is only listening for localhost (and possibly the ip)

Comment: I have tried changing the "localhost" to "public dns" of that instance. Still the issue persists.

Comment: This is a duplicate see my response to the same problem here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32483013/610390

Comment: Hey, I couldn't solve the problem. I switched to GCE instead of AWS.
It is working fine with GCE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Self hosting Web API with OWIN on EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26006284/self-hosting-web-api-with-owin-on-ec2)

Answer (score 0):

You're starting the `WebApp` on localhost:

`http://localhost:65435`

It's started on the loopback adapter and not on the actual ethernet adapter that you're trying to access from outside. You need to start it with the server's ip.

Comment: I have replaced the "localhost" with "public dns" of the aws instance. But no luck, i will try with the IP address.

Comment: Yes, and did that do anything?

Comment: No, While giving the IP Address application throws an Exception.
"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

Comment: Possible permission issue? Even on the local machine I need elevated permission to host the service. Might come in combination with a firewall issue, so make sure you open the desired port for access from remote.